# How to start the "Users & accounts" settings page?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I'd like to show the sync settings for an `AccountManager` / `SyncAdapter` account - and the account is even created by the app which tries to show it (the content authorities would also match). But how to indirectly start the `UserAndAccountDashboardActivity` with an `Intent`? The settings page equaling `Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES` (email) even seems to be one level deeper.

This `Intent` works on Android OS - but on Harmony OS it shows me the `WifiSettingsActivity`.

```
protected void showSyncSettings(@NonNull String authority) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS);
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES, new String[] {authority});
    try {
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This issue is [`ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS) - and `UserAndAccountDashboardActivity` is about the same:

> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this.

```
E/ActivityTaskManager: START {act=android.settings.SYNC_SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 hwFlg=0x10 cmp=com.android.settings/.HWSettings} result: 3
```

What I've tried so far, is to start the `UserAndAccountDashboardActivity` directly:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$UserAndAccountDashboardActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Which suggests, that one cannot start the `UserAndAccountDashboardActivity` directly:

> W/ActivityTaskManager: Permission Denial: starting `Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$UserAndAccountDashboardActivity (has extras) }` from `ProcessRecord{e07293d 8294:com.acme.debug/u0a208} (pid=8294, uid=10208)` not exported from uid 1000.

When starting it with `adb shell am` it doesn't do much either:

```
HWWGR:/ $ am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings -e :android:show_fragment com.android.settings.Settings$UserAndAccountDashboardActivity
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings (has extras) }
```

---

This seems to be the main settings page, from where the user still has to scroll down 2-3 screens:

```
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.HWSettings");
```

And I can start most other sub-pages of `Settings` / `extends HWSettings` directly:

`BluetoothSettingsActivity` •
`WirelessSettingsActivity` •
`TetherSettingsActivity` •
`VpnSettingsActivity` •
`DateTimeSettingsActivity` •
`WifiSettingsActivity` •
`LocalePickerActivity` •
`UserDictionarySettingsActivity` •
`SoundSettingsActivity` •
`DisplaySettingsActivity` •
`DeviceInfoSettingsActivity` •
`ManageApplicationsActivity` •
`StorageUseActivity` •
`DevelopmentSettingsActivity` •
`AccessibilitySettingsActivity` •
`CaptioningSettingsActivity` •
`LocationSettingsActivity` •
`RunningServicesActivity` •
`PowerUsageSummaryActivity` •
`CryptKeeperSettingsActivity` •
`DeviceAdminSettingsActivity` •
`DataUsageSummaryActivity` •
`AdvancedWifiSettingsActivity` •
`TextToSpeechSettingsActivity` •
`WifiDisplaySettingsActivity` •
`DreamSettingsActivity` •
`UserSettingsActivity` •
`NotificationAccessSettingsActivity` •
`TrustedCredentialsSettingsActivity` •
`PrintSettingsActivity`

There's even further sub-pages, which one can directly start:

```
HWWGR:/ $ dumpsys package | grep -Eo "^[[:space:]]+[0-9a-f]+[[:space:]]+com.android.settings/[^[:space:]]+" | grep -oE "[^[:space:]]+$" | grep Settings\\$
```

This also provides some vendor-specific sub-classes, eg. the `StorageDashboardActivity`.

---

But how would the `Intent` have to look alike, which opens the desired `UserAndAccountDashboardActivity` directly or indirectly? I've also tried `Intent` `com.android.settings/.SubSettings`, but this cannot be started either:

```
HWWGR:/ $ am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings }
Security exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings } from null (pid=28606, uid=2000) not exported from uid 1000
```

Comment: Might have to start `DeviceInfoSettingsActivity` and click update until it reads Harmony OS 2.0.1.